# Deep pipeline - cpu architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-pipelines

I was reading and learning about SIMD and [AVX2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-intel-avx2-improves-performance-on-server-applications) vector instruction, as I was trying to implement them for better performance.

While reading about vector instruction, I encountered the term deep pipeline. Now I understand what pipelining is from **computer organization and design patterson & hennessy** and **Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach**. I quickly again scanned the books mentioned and they do not explain deep pipelining with a example and just mention about it in a couple of sentences. I tried to do a google search and I encountered the same material as mentioned in the comments(which 99% talk about pipelining and not deep pipelining) which again just mention about deep pipelining in a couple of sentences (deep pipeline = more stages, splitting of instruction leads to quick execution ) . But, what I am looking for is a simple example of deep pipelining(and not pipelining) with good explanation of it as in how the instruction are split and how it leads to quicker execution.

So, the goal was to learn how to use vector instruction and later on GPU programming and while doing so, I encountered text which mentioned the use of deep pipeline with vector instruction. And, I am short of time, I spend some hours looking for deep pipeline on google and whatever I found was a couple of sentences explaining it and not a working example, to practically understand and visualize how a deep pipelining works.

So, I will appreciate if someone could point me to a resource which has a working example of deep pipelining with some explanation.

Comment: Valid recap questions after an introduction to *pipelining*. The effect of assignments tends to be lacking on anyone not doing them.

Comment: @user2166888 Have you done prior study on pipelining before asking the question? If yes, it would be a better idea to ask a specific concept which is not clear. There are a lot of straightforward resources and can answer all of your general questions above. I'd start here (Wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining]

Comment: @ss09 i do understand what pipelining is very well. and the wikipedia article that you mention, I scanned it and there is only one sentence about deep pipeline(As the pipeline is made "deeper" (with a greater number of dependent steps), a given step can be implemented with simpler circuitry, which may let the processor clock run faster).I was studying SIMD and there I encountered deep pipeline in a example. And they donot mention what exactly is deep pipeline in detail or how pipeline is made deeper with a example. i tried to google it, but everywhere I find one sentence reply to deep pipeline

Comment: I was able to find a couple of pages/documents which mention the concept with a little more detail. [link1 CS@University of Alaska](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2011/spring/cs641/proj1/acornachione/) and [link2 CS@Stony Brook](https://compas.cs.stonybrook.edu/course/cse502-s13/lectures/cse502-L4-pipelining.pdf). I hope this helps.

Comment: We recommend you do a significant amount of research (on the topic of pipelining) before asking (e.g., reading standard textbooks would be a good start).  Then, tell us what you do and don't understand, what your thoughts are, and make the question interesting by providing some background.  In this case it's not clear what prevents you from answering.  Perhaps you don't know what deep pipelining is.  Perhaps you haven't read much about pipelining.  Perhaps you haven't tried to reason through the question yourself.  Perhaps you have and got stuck on something.  Hard to tell.

Comment: ok @D.W. thanks for the tip. I will edit my question based on your suggestions. I guess the way I asked the question was naive. I will edit it and construct it better

Comment: @ss09 I went through the links you posted and the were the links which I encounter during google search and the describe deep pipelining in one or two sentences but I was trying to look for a elaborate working example. but I will rephrase my question. I guess the way I framed my question is naive

Comment: (There is more than one reason why deep pipelines have somewhat fallen out of favour compared to the days of, say, the CDC-7600 (when it may have been called super-pipelining). Find some! (Has there been a renaissance? Going strong?…))

Comment: What is the difference between "slow cars" and "fast cars"? They are the same except for speed. Processors with a deep pipeline just have more pipeline stages.

Comment: i was looking for a simple practical example as in how does deep pipeline makes things fast and how do different stages communicate with each other after splitting the instruction. I read the text "splitting instruction, deeper pipeline" makes everything fast. Splitting instruction feels like could make things faster as you can pipeline more. But I wanted to practically understand how does splitting instruction makes things faster and how do different stages communicate with each other after splitting instruction. A small example would have sufficed. Anyways thank you everyone for your input.